# Tinymce double click insert new paragraph

Tags: javascript, tinymce

If I have 2 tables directly under each other with margin-bottom, is it impossible to place the cursor in this gap by creating a temporary paragraph.

E.g I want to insert a new table between the other 2. This is impossible without altering the HTML directly.

Is it possible to use the [double click](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onDblClick) so that it works similar to MS word and creates a blank paragraph in this area you click, this would then get replace by the table etc similar to how the trailing plugin works.

I currently use the '[trailing](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2818358&group_id=103281&atid=738747)' plugin which fixes this similar issue at the bottom of the page.

Also I am using the jquery version of tinymce, if that makes it any easier to fix this.

**Example HTML inside tinymce editor;**

```
<table style="margin: 15px 0; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                Product Name</th>
            <th scope="col">
                Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Large product</td>
            <td><a href="http://example.com">Find out more</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Large product</td>
            <td><a href="http://example.com">Find out more</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table style="margin: 15px 0; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                Product Name</th>
            <th scope="col">
                Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Large product</td>
            <td><a href="http://example.com">Find out more</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Large product</td>
            <td><a href="http://example.com">Find out more</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also created a jsFiddle with example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Sicaab/2 I want to be able to insert extra content (paragraph,another table, list etc) between the 2 tables without editing the HTML.

Comment: to be 100% sure what you mean: can you show me the relecant content of your editor as html code to the point of time when you want to double click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse position won't help you, because you do not know if the editor content has been scrolled or not.

First, i will show you how to work with the onDblClick.

Here is a helpfull function to get the paragraph of an editor html element (in case there are no html elements that are not stacked under(or better in) a paragraph.

```
function table_of_click(node)
{
    while (node)
    {
      if (node.nodeName == 'BODY') { return null; }
      if (node.nodeName == 'TABLE')    { return node; }
      else { node = node.parentNode; }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Here is the necessary call to catch the double click event.
Be aware that this solution will add a paragraph just before the paragraph you clicked in.
I assume your tables are in a paragraph each?

```
ed.onDblClick.add(function(ed, evt){


  // get tableof click event
  var table = table_of_click(evt.target);

  // if the click has not been inside a table return (nothing to do)
  if (!table) return;

  $(table).before("<p id='new_p'><br></p>");
  ed.selection.select( $(ed.getBody()).find('#new_p').get(0) );

  $('.new_p:first').remove();
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: No this need to be valid HTML so a table could never be inside a `p`. I am sure you will have come across this similar issue with a image/table there is no way to insert something in between.

Comment: Your example shows how to insert a table with HTML, although I dont want to automatically insert anything. Only place the cursor in a "gap" (has to be an empty paragraph) so that they can then edit this as they wish

Comment: ok, i think i know what you want - i will update my answer. btw a table can be inside a paragraph (depends on the definition of valid) :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the caret (text cursor) position into the text
[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea#answer-263796)
this is just a function `getCaret(element);`

now we need to capture the tinymce container's body inside the iframe `content_ifr`
the iframe: `document.getElementById("content_ifr")`
the tinymce's body: `...contentDocument.getElementById("tinymce")`

using jquery we listen to the `dblclick` event:
`.dblclick(function(event){})`
find the caret and inject a `<p>` element on its position.
`html.substr(0,position)+"<p></p>"+html.substr(position)`
that is, all the text from the start to position, the p element and the text from the position to the end.

The whole code will look like this:

```
var editor = document.getElementById("content_ifr").contentDocument.getElementById("tinymce");

$(editor).dblclick(function(event){
    var position = getCaret(this);
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.substr(0,position)+"<p></p>"+this.innerHTML.substr(position);
}
```

this should do the job ;)